# Receiving Duplicate Results When Querying information_schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I'm running a quick query to make sure that all the foreign keys in my table are referencing a field that is indexed.

My code is as follows:

```
select table_name, column_name, index_name from statistics where table_name in (select referenced_table_name from key_column_usage where table_name='table' and table_schema='schema') and column_name in (select referenced_column_name from key_column_usage where table_name='table' and table_schema='schema') order by table_name;
```

I'm running this on multiple environments, but for some reason I'm receiving duplicate results on one particular environment. The tables are all set up the same, however, so I'm not sure what is causing this behavior.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This for InnoDB tables? The FK constraints could not have been created in the first place if the referenced columns were not indexed. MySQL would error with 1215, I believe. An index is a prerequisite for FK creation.

Comment: Yes, these are InnoDB tables. The strange behavior is only found one on environment of many... I don't understand this issue I'm having with duplicate records. Each index is listed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that mysql server you probably have 2 databases (schemas) with the same structure or you have multi-column foreign keys. Include the table_schema field in the select list of the outer query to confirm.

Use a multi-column `in` operator or inner join instead of multiple single column `in` operators in the where clause of your query.

Comment: Yes, there were unexpected schemas skewing the results. Thank you!